# JMS transaction roll back in WSO2 ESB4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've created a JMS listener as below. Everything is working fine as the listener is able to receive the messages from Q. But when my end point is down due to some reasons the message is not roll backing to Q. Would like to know the jms transaction boundary & will I be able to roll back transactoion if my end point fails. Currently it's not happening, anything I am missing here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TestJMSListener"
       transports="jmslistener1,jmslistener2"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint key="StoreJMSMSg"/>
         </call>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">TestQueue</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you also set the following in axis2.xml?

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Guaranteed Delivery EIP ensures safe delivery of a message by storing it locally and transmitting it to the receiver's data store. Even when the receiver is offline, the EIP ensures that the message goes through when the receiver comes online.

Using message stores and message processors you can overcome this. Please refer the [link](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/01/guaranteed-delivery-with-Message-Store-Message-Processor%20/).